# Combining codes in one concise code in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'region'  : ['a', 'a', 'a','b','b','b','c','c','c','c','d','d','d','f','f','f','f','g','g','g','g','g'],
    'month' : [8,9,10,12,1,2,8,9,10,11,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,8,9,10,11,12],
    'incident_count' : [5,7,3, 34,23,29,5,2,5,4,12,21,15,34,41,35,14,  25,32,43,21,19]})
```

I performed the following operations:

```
df = df.groupby(['region', 'month']).incident_count.sum().reset_index()
```

calculated the slope per region :

```
from scipy.stats import linregress

df1 = df.groupby('region').apply(lambda v: linregress(v.month, v.incident_count)[0]).reset_index()
```

Now I want to have these codes on one line of code. How can i do that?

Comment: what do you mean by 'one concise code' ? just one line of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not too sure why you would want to write a one-liner since it would look huge.

The obvious answer would be just to pipe the two lines you wrote

```
df.groupby(['region', 'month']).incident_count.sum().reset_index().groupby('region').apply(lambda v: linregress(v.month, v.incident_count)[0]).reset_index()
```

You could give us more info on what exactly you are trying to do

Comment: I want to add this to a dashboard later and I am being asked to try to get the same information with just one line of code. I am new to this and still wondering around. If you have any other opproach this I'd like to hear it.